# Send direct message to new members from target telegram group

Tags: python, telegram, telethon, py-telegram-bot-api, reply

i want to make a script, that get the user_id from new joined members in a target group, and send to new member a direct message, how i can do that?

I didn't know what to try.

Comment: SO is not a code writing service. Put some effort into figuring out how to use the Telegram API, then ask if you have issues with the code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think its a welcome message from new member. You can try this code. Correct me if i wrong.

```
@bot.on(events.ChatAction)
async def handler(event):

if event.user_joined:
    await event.reply('Your Custom Message')
    print(event.sender.id)
```

With this code, will send a new message when nember joined to your group and print their user_id to your terminal.

Comment: Hi, thanks, i want, to get the user_id from members what have just joined and initiate a chat with it and send a custom message in direct message